# Check all the children for XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have `XElement` object which is my XML tree read from XML file. Now I want to check all the nodes in this tree to get first attribute name and value. Is there any simple way to go through all of the nodes (from root till leaves)? My XML file has got very many different and strange nodes - that's why it's harder to solve this issue. I thought about writing some recursion, but hope it's another way to solve that easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe take a look to Xpath. an XPath like this `//*[@id=42]` could do the job.

It means get all nodes which have an attribute "id" of value 42.

You can do just `//*` which gonna returns all nodes in a tree.

Xpath :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms950786.aspx

Syntax :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256471.aspx

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm looking for. I can get all the paths once - while loading XML file and then I can use them to get all the nodes linearly:) Thx

Comment: You should add more restricted params in your XPath in order to be faster :), like attribute, having node "foo" as parent or stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all children elements using [`XElement.Elements()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.elements.aspx).

Here's some code using recursion to get all elements of each level:

```
void GetElements(XElement element){
    var elements = element.Elements();

    foreach(Element e in elements){
        //some stuff here

        if(e.Elements() != null)
           GetElements(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using this I will get only the children of level -1 from my XElement. Then I need to get another level by repeating .Elements(). I want to avoid it.